# How to join tables with many-to-many relationship and group by month in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables: one with Salespeople monthly targets and the other with deals they closed.

[image]

[image]

I need to consolidate the amount closed for each salesperson and month, and join with the first table. Find the expected result below.

[image]

I've tried the query below but it won't join the months if no deal was closed.

```
SELECT
         S."Salesperson",
         month(S."Date"),
         year(S."Date"),
         S."Date",
         S."Target",
         sum(D."Amount") AS 'Amount',
FROM  "SalesQuotes" AS  S
LEFT JOIN "Deals" AS  D ON D."Salesperson"  = S."Salesperson"
     AND    (year(D."Date")  = year(S."Date")
     AND    month(D."Date")  = month(S."Date"))  
GROUP BY S."Salesperson",
     month(S."Date"),
     year(S."Date"),
     S."Target",
      S."Date"
```

MREs:

First table

```
CREATE TABLE SalesQuotes(
   Date        VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,Salesperson VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,Target      INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO SalesQuotes(Date,Salesperson,Target) VALUES ('jan/21','John',12);
INSERT INTO SalesQuotes(Date,Salesperson,Target) VALUES ('feb/21','John',14);
INSERT INTO SalesQuotes(Date,Salesperson,Target) VALUES ('mar/21','John',16);
INSERT INTO SalesQuotes(Date,Salesperson,Target) VALUES ('jan/21','Mary',20);
INSERT INTO SalesQuotes(Date,Salesperson,Target) VALUES ('feb/21','Mary',25);
INSERT INTO SalesQuotes(Date,Salesperson,Target) VALUES ('mar/21','Mary',30);
INSERT INTO SalesQuotes(Date,Salesperson,Target) VALUES ('jan/21','George',50);
INSERT INTO SalesQuotes(Date,Salesperson,Target) VALUES ('feb/21','George',60);
INSERT INTO SalesQuotes(Date,Salesperson,Target) VALUES ('mar/21','George',70);
```

Second table

```
CREATE TABLE Deals(
   Date        VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,Salesperson VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,Amount      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Deal        VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Deals(Date,Salesperson,Amount,Deal) VALUES ('jan/21','John',5,'A');
INSERT INTO Deals(Date,Salesperson,Amount,Deal) VALUES ('jan/21','John',6,'B');
INSERT INTO Deals(Date,Salesperson,Amount,Deal) VALUES ('feb/21','Mary',10,'C');
INSERT INTO Deals(Date,Salesperson,Amount,Deal) VALUES ('feb/21','George',15,'D');
INSERT INTO Deals(Date,Salesperson,Amount,Deal) VALUES ('mar/21','George',40,'E');
```

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? Please do not tag databases that are not relevant

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've removed the tags.

Comment: Your query looks correct.

Comment: I had a WHERE clause that was messing up with the query. Ironically, when I wrote down this question, I left it out and it's now working fine 